# Tree in Go referencing father id

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a tree in Go, but Im having a little problem to create this tree, Im receiving from a .txt disorderly names:

```
SESSION01.5
SESSION01
SESSION02.5
SESSION01.5.5
SESSION02
```

It should be:

```
SESSION01 -> SESSION01.5 -> SESSION01.5.5
SESSION02 -> SESSION02.5
```

Im ordening to add in database, because I need the father's id to set in my struct Session as:

```
type Session struct {
  ID *int64
  Name *string
  SessionFatherID *int64
}
```

Any idea how to create this tree?

Comment: That's a [forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Forest), not a tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question, do you need to have a reference on your Session struct.  It would be better if it was written:

```
type Session struct {
   ID int64
   Name string
   SessionFatherID int64
}
```

The easiest thing to do is read this into a map with the `Name` as the key and then do a second pass to associate the `SessionFatherID` (aka parent ID).

Since this feels like homework, I'll avoid the "write the solution for you".  Your program should look like:

Step 1:
  Open the input file

Step 2:
  Scan the input file into a map of sessions: `sessions := map[string]*Session{}`

```
entry := Session{ID: id, Name: name}
session[entry.Name] = &entry
```

Step 3:
  Iterate over the sessions

- Parse the session name to get it's parent
- Lookup in the map the parent and it's ID
- Set the entry to have the new `SessionFatherID`

  ```
   if parent, found := sessions[parentSessionName]; found {
          value.SessionFatherID = parent.ID
   }
  ```
- This works since the map is to a pointer of Session, you can change the value

Step 4:
  Output your result

A simple result for your given dataset might look like:

```
&{1 SESSION01 0}
&{2 SESSION02.5 4}
&{3 SESSION01.5.5 0}
&{4 SESSION02 0}
&{0 SESSION01.5 1}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. "Lookup in the map the parent and it's ID" -> I didn't understand one thing: how can I be sure it was registered in database (his parent), a map doesn't has a order, right? Firstly, I need to register his parent for to add the new Session referencing his parent ID.

Comment: I understand, sorry, I'll implement that, I bring a feedback later, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to do this as a multi-pass operation. In the first pass, read in all your session names and create a `Session` struct with nil pointers for ID and parent ID. Also add them to a `map[string]*Session` (keyed on the name). You will also need a "parent session name from session name" function (which from the looks of your example data would be "if there are any dots, drop the last dot and anything after").

That should allow you to reconstruct the tree after reading the data. It will also require some fiddling with how you send things to (and read things from) the database, to ensure that you create session records at the appropriate time.

Comment: I was thinking about ordering the names and setting up my tree as a array, because as I need the parent ID, I would try to register first 'SESSION01', and as the array is ordenered, after I register 'SESSION01.5' getting his parent ID. I din't understand how to make that with a map.

Comment: I understand, sorry, I'll implement that, I bring a feedback later, thanks!